# pass value from JSF 2.1 to bean and get ArrayList from bean(No Annotations)

Tags: jsf-2

I am new to JSF, what would the sample codes when the JSF page loads and passes a value to a Bean and get results set back as an ArrayList to the same JSF. The JSF 2.1 without using Annotations.I want to pass a value from JSF to a bean and get the result set as a List.
Mk

Comment: can you please explain flow which type you want? so i will help you

Comment: "passes a value" is ambiguous. Please edit and clarify. How/where exactly is that value defined? Is it a GET request parameter? Or is it hardcoded in a XHTML template? Etc. Almost all approaches have already been asked and answered before if you know the right terms.

Comment: Lets say I have the following codes in JSF:       <h:outputFormat value="#{massages.logged}"> <f:param value="#{bean.id}"/>               </h:outputFormat> , now i want to pass bean,id value to a java beans and get rsults as a list in the same page without using the submit button  or a link